# Problems with Code from SVN

Tags: xcode, svn, linker-errors

I have a problem with my iOS code when pulling it from the SVN. My code works fine on my MAC, but after I upload it to SVN and try to build my project it shows the same error over and over.

> Apple Mach-O Linker (id) error
>
> ld: library not found for -lzbar
>   Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

This problem is pretty annoying and makes my work on the code very difficult. Here is the complete error:

> Ld /Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SmartDealer-hezswmtfdvujkibrhkmqudlypdqk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SmartDealer.app/SmartDealer normal i386
>       cd "/Users/administrator/Desktop/test/Trade-In 4S"
>       setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
>       setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin"
>       /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SmartDealer-hezswmtfdvujkibrhkmqudlypdqk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator "-L/Users/administrator/Desktop/test/Trade-In 4S" "-L/Users/administrator/Desktop/test/Trade-In 4S/Classes/ZBarSDK" "-L/Users/administrator/Desktop/test/Trade-In 4S/ZBarSDK" -F/Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SmartDealer-hezswmtfdvujkibrhkmqudlypdqk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SmartDealer-hezswmtfdvujkibrhkmqudlypdqk/Build/Intermediates/SmartDealer.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SmartDealer.build/Objects-normal/i386/SmartDealer.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40000 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreData -lsqlite3 -framework QuartzCore -weak_framework CoreMedia -weak_framework CoreVideo -liconv -lzbar -weak_framework AVFoundation -o /Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SmartDealer-hezswmtfdvujkibrhkmqudlypdqk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SmartDealer.app/SmartDealer
>
> ld: library not found for -lzbar
>   Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the 'ZBarSDK' folder was successfully included in SVN? It seems that you're trying to link to a framework in that folder, so you should either find a standardized location for the framework and install it on all development machines, or leave your project alone but make sure that the ZBarSDK folder is successfully added to your SVN repo along with your other source.

You can do this from the command line--just `cd` into your project folder and `svn add ZBarSDK`.

Comment: Thank you very much Andy. The ZBarSDK was uploaded, but there was one *.a file missing and SVN clients ignores all *.a files.

I solved the problem by downloading following plugin: SCPlugin (http://scplugin.tigris.org/). With this plugin I could add files manually.